# Google Maps infowindow shows same content for each marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm working on a problem involving Google Maps API and infowindows. When I click on a marker, an infowindow pops up, and I am trying to make it so that when that happens, the lat/lng for that marker is displayed in the infowindow. The lat/lng in this case being stored in the stops array:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker;
    var infowindow;   //Global infowindow created
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.784, -122.408);
        var stops = new Array();
        stops = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(37.7655, -122.4525899),
     new google.maps.LatLng(37.7649999, -122.45656),
     new google.maps.LatLng(37.7643, -122.4608199),

     ];
        var myOptions = {
             zoom: 10,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
             center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7655, -122.4525899)

        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("content"),
    myOptions);
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({   //infowindow options set
            maxWidth: 355
        });

        var i = 0;
        for (i < 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:stops[i],
                map: map,
                title: "Stop Coords: "+ stops[i]
            });
            var len=stops.length;
            popupDirections(marker, len, stops);
        }
    }

    function popupDirections(marker, len,stops) {
        //this function created listener listens for click on a marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            { infowindow.setContent("Stop coords: " + stops[i]); } //sets the content of your global infowindow to string "Tests: "
            infowindow.open(map, marker); //then opens the infowindow at the marker
        });
    }
```

Now, when I hover the mouse over each marker, the correct lat/lng is shown, but when I click on the marker and the infowindow pops up, I keep getting the lat/lng of stops[2]. I am not sure what the problem is, my knowledge of JS is pretty limited, I was fortunate to find a helpful post earlier on here that showed how to create infowindows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to tackle your problem is to give each marker the Custom Object Property `stopCoords`:

```
for (i < 0; i < stops.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: stops[i],
        map: map,
        title: "Stop Coords: " + stops[i],
        stopCoords: stops[i]
    });
    var len = stops.length;
    popupDirections(marker, len, stops);
}
```

Then, in the `popupDirections` function, refer back to it (**UPDATE** or use `marker.position` instead. But the point is, you can make `stopCoords` be any value you wish).

```
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        infowindow.setContent("Stop coords: " + marker.stopCoords);
    }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/580/

I'll throw some buzzwords to explain why your original code doesn't work: has to do with variable scope and closures.

Comment: This JSFiddle is missing :(